# Can arm-none-eabi-gcc generate .dfu files directly?

Tags: gcc, arm, dfu

I see claims e.g., [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2018/jan/update-firmware-field-using-microcontroller-dfu-mode) that GCC can generate `.dfu` files for STM32 DfuSe. Is it true? Is at an option on `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` or another part of the toolchain?